# radioMatrixInput from shinySurvey doesn't work with incomplete responses

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm working with this package (shinySurveys) and I can use it pretty easily. I'm facing one issue regarding the radioMatrixInput object. I can't seem to get the responses out of the object unless all options are completed, and that's my challenge, the user can leave some options unanswered. So, if question has 4 options, he can answer 2 and leave 2 without selecting an option for them.

I'm providing an example of the behaviour I'm describing. I've tried observe and observeEvent but both didn't work.

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  df <- data.frame(
    question = c(rep("I love sushi.", 3), rep("I love chocolate.",3), rep("I love vegetables.",3)),
    option = c(rep(c("Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree"), 3)),
    input_type = c(rep("matrix", 9)),
    # For matrix questions, the IDs should be the same for each question
    # but different for each matrix input unit
    input_id = c(rep("matId", 9)),
    dependence = NA,
    dependence_value = NA,
    required = FALSE
  )
  
  library(shiny)
  library(shinySurveys)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    surveyOutput(df),
    verbatimTextOutput('debug01')
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    renderSurvey()

    observe({
      print(input$matId)
    })
      
    output$debug01 <- renderPrint({input$matId})
    
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      print(input$matId)
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Congrats, you completed your first shinysurvey!",
        "You can customize what actions happen when a user finishes a survey using input$submit."
      ))
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  
}
```

This works fine as long as I provide an answer to all the option. When I select only one option, the object doesn't get any answers back to my print function in the server.

Any of you would happen to know how to access that data from the server part of shiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime thinking about this I have solved my own challenge. What I've done is I've created an extended input type using the object **radioMatrixInput** from the package **[shinyRadioMatrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyRadioMatrix/shinyRadioMatrix.pdf)**. The matrix radio input already exist in shinysurveys but as I explained in my issue above it requires the user to always respond all questions before one can extract the answers with the function getSurveyData and in my case users should only respond 2 of the 4 options per question. On the contrary, this new radioMatrixInput allows me to get the answers only 2 answers from the users leaving the other 2 blanks.

For this to work I had to re-arrange the options for each question into one line so they can be assigned to my new extended input type, let's call it 'matx'. The definition of this new type is as follow:

```
extendInputType(input_type = "matx", {
  shinyRadioMatrix::radioMatrixInput(
    inputId = surveyID(),
    rowIDs = unlist(strsplit(surveyLabel(), ",")),
    selected = NULL,
    rowLLabels = c("","","",""),
    choices = unlist(strsplit(surveyOptions(), ",")),
    rowIDsName = paste("Question",substr(surveyID(), 11,12))
  )
})
```

For this extension to work one has to use the helper functions: surveyID(), surveyLabel() and surveyOptions(). The last two bring back the question and the options from the dataframe that holds the questions.

As for my dataframe, each question contains four questions separated by comma, same with the options. In my case options are always two (most and least). see image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5QY6.png)

So considering that the helper functions will return a vector of strings separated by commas I have used **strsplit** and **unlist** to separate the questions and convert them into a vector that radioMatrixInput can use and read.

After doing that this is how my questions look in shiny:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMJ6R.png)

There you have it, hope this helps anyone facing a similar challenge than mine.

All the best!